# Java Code for files to Excell

Tags: java, eclipse, file, apache-poi, filenames

I need to convert txt files to one Excel file and further format each work book.
Converting all txt files to excel is done but problems is to format each work sheet according to its rows and columns.For eg in first sheet need to merge (0,0,14,18) and in second sheet need to merge (1,2,0,0). I tried using sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0,0,14,17)); but it will merge same cells of all the worksheet. below is my code plz help.

```
package csv2excell;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.model.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class csv2excell{

private static void printUsage(int errorCode, String string) {
    System.out.println("Usage: <scriptName> csvPath outputFileName csvfileName1 csvfileName2 and so on....");
    if(errorCode == 1) System.out.println("Incorrect number of arguments, script will now exit");
    if(errorCode == 2) System.out.println("Specified directory "+string+" does not exist, script will now exit");
    if(errorCode == 3) System.out.println("Error reading files from "+string+" , script will now exit");
    System.exit(-1);
}

private static void makeRowBold(HSSFWorkbook wb, Row row){
    CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();//Create style
    Font font = wb.createFont();//Create font
    style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);//Make font bold
    style.setFont(font);//set it to bold
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    for(int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++){//For each cell in the row 
        row.getCell(i).setCellStyle(style);//Set the style
    }
}


public static void main(String[]args){
    if(args.length < 3) printUsage(1,null);
    try{

        File folder = new File(args[0]);
        if(!folder.isDirectory()) printUsage(2,args[0]);
            File[] listOfFiles = new File[args.length-2];
            for (int i=2;i<args.length;i++) {
            listOfFiles[i-2] = new File(args[0]+"/"+args[i]);
            // System.out.println("Reading "+args[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<listOfFiles.length;i++) {
            String filename = (listOfFiles[i].getName());
        //System.out.println(filename);

        }


        HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook();
        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        Font font = workbook.createFont();//Create font
        font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);//Make font bold
        style.setFont(font);//set it to bold

        for (File file : listOfFiles) {

            if (file.isFile()) {

                String thisline;
                ArrayList<String> al = null;
                ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

                HSSFSheet sheet =  workbook.createSheet(file.getName());  
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
                int LineNum=0;
                while ((thisline = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    //System.out.println("DEBUG: "+file.getName()+":"+thisline);
                    al = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String strar[] = thisline.split(",");

                    for (int j = 0; j < strar.length; j++) { 
                        //System.out.println("here");
                        al.add(strar[j]);
                    }

                    arlist.add(al);
                    for (int k = 0; k < arlist.size(); k++) {
                        //System.out.println("here1");
                        ArrayList<String> ardata = (ArrayList<String>) arlist.get(k);

                        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) k);

                        for (int p = 0; p < ardata.size(); p++) {

                            HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) p);
                            cell.setCellValue(ardata.get(p).toString());

                            if(p == 0) {
                                cell.setCellStyle(style);

                                //System.out.println(LineNum+":"+p);

                            }
                        }
                    }



                    /*    System.out.println("DEBUG: arlist size before"+arlist.size());
                    arlist.add(al);
                    System.out.println("DEBUG: arlist size after"+arlist.size());*/
                    // LineNum++;

                }

                makeRowBold(workbook, sheet.getRow(0));
                fis.close(); 
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(args[0]+"/"+args[1]);
                sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0,0,14,17));
                workbook.write(fileOut);
                fileOut.flush();
                fileOut.close();
                br.close();

            }

        }


    System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated at "+args[0]+"/"+args[1]+"!");

    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}


private static void printIn(boolean filenumber) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0,0,14,17));` in the `for` loop. This will merge these ranges for all sheets you are creating.

You need to add a verification (such as a simple variable `i` counting the iterations), and merge the ranges you want for each iteration.

In your case, it could be

```
if(i==0){
    //first sheet
    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0,0,14,17));
} else if (i==1){
    //second sheet
    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1,2,0,0));
}
```